# Good way to show the css properties of an object

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a 'preview' of the current CSS applied to an object. The object is basically a square that may have text inside it, a border, a background, etc. For example:

[image]

However, I'm wondering how I can show things 'outside' the box. For example, if I have a `margin: 2px 3px 4px 5px`. How could I show that?

The point of this is to have a 'preview' element for a user so they can adjust some properties and see how it looks on the screen. Everything within the 'box' inclusive of the border I know how to show but I'm not too sure how to show what may be outside the border, such as a margin. What might be the best way to do this?

Here is a reference codepen: https://codepen.io/dmoniker2147/pen/MWmKrrR.

Comment: Will this help in your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle?

Comment: @TusharShahi sure...but in that preview box how would you convey margin?

Comment: You will get the styles and values right? Can you not show them in a list?

Comment: @TusharShahi what do you mean "a list" ? The user enters in the styles (in a list), I want to show how it would look in a Preview...

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect an element or open Developer tools, selecting element from the page or directly from code in Element.  Select the tab labeled **Computed** on the top of the rightmost column. Then you will see the **box model** where you can visualize the margin and padding, border etc.

For more detailed info [here](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/f1-devtools-box-model).